# Randomly generate char array without duplicate index

Tags: java, android

Want to generate randomly characters store in a char array without duplicate index and store them in a new ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Character> al = new ArrayList<>();
char letters[ ] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
for(int i =0; i<letters.length; i++){
    al.add(letters[ i ]);
}
ArrayList<Character> al2 = new ArrayList<>();
Random random = new Random ();
while (al.size() > 0) {
    int randomizedNumber = random.nextInt(al.size());
    al2.add(letters[ randomizedNumber ]; //adding randomized charterer in the new ArrayList.
    al.remove(letters[ randomizedNumber ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to randomize the order of the array you can use `Collections.shuffle`

```
Character letters[ ] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
ArrayList<Character> a1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(letters));
Collections.shuffle(a1, new Random());
```

Comment: Worked great. But I didn't use the argument you passed to the ArrayLIst, Arrays.as list(letters). Once again thanks.